# Protractor Third party login: This site cannot be reached

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing, okta

I am having a problem with my test; I understand why it is happening so I am  looking for advice on can be done. I have an angular app that uses a third party log in service (okta). I am trying to do e2e tests. In order to use the app, the user must be signed in, otherwise they cannot use any of the features of the website (making testing impossible if I am not logged in). So I plan on using a prepare or beforeAll/each function to sign in. Have not decided how to implement that yet. But my problem is not that, I created a test to log in. My test brings you to the Okta log in page, enters the credentials, signs in. Then you are brought to the verification page, where again, a code is passed and the verify button is pressed. After this button is pressed, I should be returned to my angular homepage, signed in.

Now this is where the problem occurs. When the verify button is pressed, rather then be returned to my home page, I receive this error page:

[image]

Now I belive the problem is this, and correct me if I am wrong. When clicking the verify button, that should bring the user back to the Localhost:4200 page. Now protractor uses a different address. I think this may be the problem. To test this, in protractor I do this line after I am brought to the error page:

```
    browser.get('http://localhost:4200');
```

Doing so, I again get the same error. But if I do:

```
browser.get('http://localhost:49152')
```

I am brought back to my homepage, but obviously I am not signed in, so I cannot use this as a workaround. Any input would be great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a work around. Through my research I could not find a reliable way to change the port number of protractor to what I need. So in the command line, I just run:

```
ng e2e --port 4200
```

I will probably write script in my angular file so I don't have to keep typing that, but hey, it works.

Answer (score 1):

these "precondition" or Before actions need to be executed in more simple and durable way. 
For example, if you have an API of this third-part sign-in system it's always better to use it. For javascript tests exists nice library - [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

that allows you to connect service directly and parse response body in order to get all needed data to login in Angular App.

```
describe('Login: ', function () {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await createUser(); -- //the method where executed all your main precondition
    });

    beforeEach(async function () {
        await new HomePage().open();
        await expect(await login.loginButton.isPresent()).toBeTruthy('Button Sign In is not present?'))
    });

    it('First Login', async function () {
        await login.email.sendKeys(login.randomEmail);
        await login.password.sendKeys(login.passwordToUse);
        await login.loginButton.click();
        await tos.tosDo();
        });
}
```